# Title attribute loaded in addStyleSheet php code

Tags: php, css, templates

I am developing a new template for Joomla 3.2.3 with includes in it to load everything, and I am working with the attribute title in css files trying to get this result:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/ugt/css/bg2.css" type="text/css" title="high" />
```

Using this:

```
  $doc->addStyleSheet($template.'/css/bg2.css');
```

But I cant find the way to call "title" in the "addStyleSheet" way.
So how to change my PHP addStyleSheet code to generate this output including "title"?

Comment: What's your template framework? TemplatePower or what?

Comment: Tks so much, this is a template for Joomla 3.2.3